# Cant get datetime formatting right

Tags: python, django, datetime

I don't know why but I always seem to have trouble formatting dates with strptime. I really can't see where I am going wrong here but this is the error I got...

time data '2021-04-10 18:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.'

I appreciate any help you can give.

```py
    weatherDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Locally this works. Are you sure there is only one space, no hidden characters, etc.?

Comment: Nevermind. It does work. Ever since this Gitpod update a few days ago nothing has been working right. I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: you can go faster with [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work here:

```
import datetime

date_str = '2021-04-10 18:00:00'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Which gives:

```
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 10, 18, 0)
```